# timeout in a TCP connection with no exchange of data

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a C/C++ application for a TCP client and server in Linux.

Suppose that after the TCP connection is in place, neither the server nor the client sends any data at all for huge amount of time. They do not even send any heartbeat each other.

By TCP protocol, how long the connectivity is supposed to be in place?

Does the connection drop due to inactivity?

If so is there any socket option where I can specify or define any kind of timeout behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid that the only sensible answer should be *it depends*.

A TCP connection can use a number of intermediary *relays* between both ends. Each component (read each end and each relay) can have its own strategy for closing inactive connections.

A common workaround is to use [keepalive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) as an *optional* TCP feature. It consists of empty packets sent by one end when the connection is idle for  more than a defined timeout. The peer should answer with an ACK, even if it does not support the keepalive extension, which is enough to maintain the connection active at the TCP level.

In Linux for example, keepalive can be set at kernel level, and will be active for all new TCP connections. It may be a bad idea because keepalive is off by default to avoid ovehead on network. From the referenced page:

> The procedures involving keepalive use three user-driven variables:
>
> tcp_keepalive_time
>
> the interval between the last data packet sent (simple ACKs are not considered data) and the first keepalive probe; after the connection is marked to need keepalive, this counter is not used any further 
>   tcp_keepalive_intvl
>
> the interval between subsequential keepalive probes, regardless of what the connection has exchanged in the meantime
>
> tcp_keepalive_probes
>
> the number of unacknowledged probes to send before considering the connection dead and notifying the application layer

They can be set for example with `sysctl(8)`:

> ```
>  # sysctl -w \
>  > net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=600 \
>  > net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 \
>  > net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=20
>  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 600
>  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 60
>  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 20
> ```

It is also possible to set it only for some connections at the application level with `setsockopt`:

> ```
>   /* Set the option active */
>   int optval = 1;
>   socklen_t optlen = sizeof(optval);
>   if(setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, optlen) < 0) {
>      perror("setsockopt()");
>      close(s);
>      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>   }
> ```

Comment: 'The peer should answer with an ACK, even if it does not support the keepalive extension' is meaningless. It can't *not* support the keepalive extension, as all that it is is sending an empty packet with an expired sequence number, which by RFC 793 must be answered by an ACK with the currently expected sequence number.

Comment: so if the connection stays alive..why all servers and clients sends HEARTBEAT each other? Is it just to save resources on the server side (in case the client goes down the server might free pc resources). Or any other issue with sockets?

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile  The problem servers have is telling the difference between a client that is alive but currently silent; and a client that has crashed, lost network connection etc.  The server needs to recover resources else a simple denial of service attack would be to connect then drop the physical layer without closing the TCP/IP connection.   The server would quickly run out of resources.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile: TCP keepalive is off by default and can be unavailable on some systems. So it makes sense to add that functionality in higher protocol levels.

Answer (score 2):

> By TCP protocol, how long the connectivity is supposed to be in place?

Forever.

> Does the connection drop due to inactivity?

No.

> If so is there any socket option where I can specify or define any kind of timeout behaviour?

There is SO_RCVTIMEO, where supported. This provides a read timeout for the `recv()` method and friends.

Comment: Can you elaborate on SO_RCVTIMEO option.

Answer (score 2):

With select ? [Select - Linux manuel page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)